# Is this a right horizontal menu technique?

Tags: css, menu

My CSS is:

```css
#menu {
    background-color: #a40a0a;
    width: 830px;
    height: 36px;
    position: relative;
    top: 39px;
    left: 172px;
}
#menu >ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#menu ul li {
    font-family: Arial, Helvatica, Verdana;
}
#menu ul li >a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 36px;
    width: 166px;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu ul li >a:hover {
    background-color: #d74343;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #bc1515;
    line-height: 34px;
}
#menu ul li >a:active {
    background-color: #a40a0a;
}
```

This menu does not look right ie7 and belows. If this is wrong, please tell me the right, thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/a4Qe3/ here is the link

Comment: And where is your HTML markup? Even better - create a [JSFiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo so people can look at it and play around

Comment: `font-family: Arial Helvatica Verdana;` - should be comma-separated.

Comment: I suppose the anchors are the only children o the LI elements. In that case, don't float the anchors, setting display:block on the anchors gets the job done.

Comment: i'm sorry  here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/a4Qe3/

Comment: Why `#menu > ul` - that's the only selector that's problematic in IE7 and older.  Any reason not to just use `#menu ul` ?  Same with `#menu ul li > a` that one SHOULD be `menu ul li a`.

Comment: because of  > points child element and space ( #menu ul ) points descendant elemnts?

Comment: `>` does work in IE7. Just not in IE6 or less. Also it makes sense in a menu that will probably have sub menus.

Comment: ie tester does not show right ie7 and less...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `float` on the `li` instead of the `a`. This is bacause the li will block each time.

Here is the the updated code:

**CSS**

```css
#menu {
    background-color: #a40a0a;
    width: 830px;
    height: 36px;
    position: relative;
    top: 39px;
    left: 172px;
}
#menu > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#menu ul li {
    font-family: Arial, Helvatica, Verdana;
    float: left;
}
#menu ul li > a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 36px;
    width: 166px;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu ul li > a:hover {
    background-color: #d74343;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #bc1515;
    line-height: 34px;
}
#menu ul li > a:active {
    background-color: #a40a0a;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a4Qe3/1/)**

**Edit 1**

We put the `float` on the `li` instead of the `a` because each `a` is wrapped in a `li` which has `display: block;` applied to each. If you think of the DOM structure, if you float the `a` tags you are floating items next to each other, that are not in the same scope. They are not DOM siblings. Their parents are. So you are just leaving their parents hanging around. Now in IE7, if you float after a blocking element, that floated item will be pushed down, as was happening in your case. So what we should do is float the `li` items.

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a4Qe3/2/) where the `a` tags are floated, and I have put a border around the `li` tags to show what is going on. Check it in IE7.

Comment: I have updated the answer trying to explain what is going on. Trying.